# WebBrowser control opens last URL in default system browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, winforms

I have a C# windows form containing a web browser control that navigates to a URL requesting some response from the server. 
Even after closing and disposing the webbrowser control and the form which contains the web browser, the application opens the webbrowser control's last navigated URL in my default system browser(chrome).

On debugging the code to find where this webbrowser call is being invoked, its found that the chrome browser is being opened at the last line where the application flow ends.

As the webbrowser control is already disposed, I am confused from where the the application gets the URL and what causes the invoking of an exterior browser.

I tried introducing some delay  to avoid this issue. But it doesn't seems to be fruitful.

I am stuck with this issue for the last two days. any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: I think you should try Stop method before disposing. `webBrowser1.Stop()`

Comment: Hi Reza..I tried that as well.sorry..but no joy..

Comment: Hi @Shammas Can you share this behavior  reproduction steps?

Comment: I am calling a form(form1) with web browser(webbrowser1) on a button click from my 'Main' form. Everything works with the web browser as expected. After performing webbrowser1.Stop(),  webbrowser1.Stop() and form1.Close() in the webbrowser1_DocumentCompleted , the control returns to the button click event in the Main form. When I tried to debug, exactly when the CLR executes closing braces of button click event, the execution stops and opens the last url of the webbrowser in my default(chrome) browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was creating the form object by using 'using' keyword, like using`(form1 frm = new form1()) {------------------ }`. What was happening here was my the form disposes all controls and the form itself after te form is closed. When I remove the using and leave the memory cleaning to the default garbage collector, my problem is solved.